# Git remote URL is not updating

Tags: git, github, git-config

GitHub wikis are also git repos, and they are only communicable through HTTPS (pull,push). I, on the other hand, have a global config to use "git://" instead of "https://". That's my preference usually, but clearly that's not the requirement in the wiki case.

Thus, I set the local git config to use "https://" instead of "git://". But this didn't work. I even set the remote URLs again, but they weren't affected at all. [Screnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7GMP.png)

I did follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801729/is-it-possible-to-have-different-git-config-for-different-projects) and [this](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/), but to no avail. Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me, as if setting a more specific URL-rewriter (that actually does NOT rewrite it) in the local repository config like this:

```
git config url.https://github.com/sakshamsaxena/sails-hook-jbvcs.wiki.git.insteadOf https://github.com/sakshamsaxena/sails-hook-jbvcs.wiki.git
```

overrides the global setting successfully and solves the problem.

Comment: Dear me, it worked! But how? It doesn't make much sense. Please explain ?

Comment: If I am to guess, this would mean that the local config is read _after_ reading the global config, where, the url rewriting is actually simply reassigning the new url to the old one. When I try to revert this in local config, the new one here is the old of the global, which is assigned the old that happens to be the new value of global, i.e., "git://". Kinda sketchy, but only such a case would the local config fail to override, imho.