# Git 2.13 conditional config on windows

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

**Git version:** 2.13.0.windows.1

**OS:** Windows 7

**CLI:** Git bash

**.gitconfig**

```
[user]
    name = Gyandeep Singh
    email = private@email.com
[push]
    default = current
[core]
    autocrlf = input
[includeIf "gitdir: ~/Documents/webstorm/corporate/"]
    path = .gitconfig-work
```

**.gitconfig-work**

```
[user]
    name = Gyandeep Singh
    email = corporate@email.com
```

- Both the config files above sit together in the same directory (home).

**What happened:** open CLI on a folder (example test) inside corporate folder and then run `git config user.email` the output is `private@email.com`.

**Expected:** Outcome should be `corporate@email.com`.

Am I doing something wrong or my expectation is not correct? I did follow the git docs.

### Solution

You have to run `git config --show-origin --get user.email` on a git initialized directory. If its not git initialized then the `includeIf gitdir` functionality will not work.

Its strange but true. I wish it still worked.

Comment: Makes sure your project is located in the directory `.../webstrom/...`. Maybe it's `webstorm`?

Comment: spelling is not the issue as i verified its the same at both places.

Comment: I have not been able to make this work either, using absolute paths `C:/...`, `C:\...` (gives error), `/c/...`. I will delve more into it tonight.

Comment: Haven't used this; but looking at the docs: have you tried removing the space between the `:` and the `~`, e.g. `[includeIf "gitdir:~/Documents/webstorm/corporate/"]`?

Comment: ...and verified that $HOME is set correctly, I suppose

Comment: $HOME is set and removing that space didn't make any difference.

Comment: Is .gitconfig-work in the same directory as .gitconfig?

Comment: yup, they sit right next to each other.

Comment: Important: the path specified by the `gitdir` clause *must* have a forward-slash at the end, otherwise it will not work. So `[includeIf "gitdir/i:~/Documents/webstorm/corporate/"]` works, but `[includeIf "gitdir/i:~/Documents/webstorm/corporate"]` does NOT. (git 2.24.1.windows.2)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Your global `C:/Users/<user-name>/.gitconfig` should have this `includeIf`:

```
[includeIf "gitdir:C:/Users/<user-name>/Documents/webstorm/corporate/"]
    path = .gitconfig-work
```

with having your work Git repos in `C:/Users/<user-name>/Documents/webstorm/corporate` and the `conditional` work configuration should be located at `C:/Users/<user-name>/.gitconfig-work`.

That's at least working for me in Window's **cmd** and **Cmder**. A `git config --show-origin --get user.email` should than show you from where a config value is loaded/resolved.

It also seems like the `conditional` work configuration is only used when issued from within a Git repository.

```
C:\Users\<user-name>\Documents\webstorm\corporate
λ git config --show-origin --get user.email
file:C:/Users/<user-name>/.gitconfig  foo@oss.com

C:\Users\<user-name>\Documents\webstorm\corporate\some-repo
λ git config --show-origin --get user.email
file:C:/Users/<user-name>/.gitconfig-work  foo@company.com

C:\Users\<user-name>\Documents\webstorm\corporate\some-non-repo-dir
λ git config --show-origin --get user.email
file:C:/Users/<user-name>/.gitconfig  foo@oss.com
```

Comment: Is the directory you run `git config --show-origin --get user.email` against a Git repository? It won't use the conditional config on a plain directory and fallback to the global config in this case.

Comment: thr you go thats the catch. I was running that command on directory which was not git initialized. When I tried it on a git repo inside corporate it worked. Thanks a,lot

Comment: also you dont have to use full path, you can use `~` as i have it in the question.

Comment: You should be also careful to use the capital drive letter (C:/) in the .gitconfig condition, not the small one. That is, if you're using absolute paths.

Comment: Watch out! Casing matters! To be sure include two `[includeIf ...]`: One with lower-case the drive letter another with upper-case! (For me Sourcetree requires upper-case, mingw console lower-case.)

Comment: Concerning Sourcetree: Do not believe what it prints in the commit area - it seems that it does not consider the `[includeIf]` (version 2.6.10.0) - but `git` will when you do the actual commit.

Comment: I had to append a trailing slash to make it work e.g. `/path/to/my/dir` doesn't work `/path/to/my/dir/` does work.

Comment: Since of Git version `2.2.20` it seems that __includeIf__ also works against non intialized repositories. So that a `git config --get user.email` will also produce `foo@company.com` when issued from the parent `C:\Users\<user-name>\Documents\webstorm\corporate` directory.

Comment: I want to have a conditional config for folders on **a network drive** `I:` (Windows). It does **not** work for me using the Drive letter `[includeIf "gitdir:I:/path/"]` - but works if I use the full network path `[includeIf "gitdir:servername/share/path/"]`. Please note that I was not able to use an absolute path starting with a slash or double slash. I just don't know the correct syntax for network shares. But if a path does not start with a slash, the conditional config applies if the pattern matches any part of the real path.

Answer (score 33):

You need to turn off case sensitivity: change `"gitdir:"` to `"gitdir/i:"`

```
[includeIf "gitdir/i:C:/Work/"]
path = .gitconfig-work

[includeIf "gitdir/i:C:/My/Dev/"]
path = .gitconfig-my
```

from:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/62921#issuecomment-437693020

Comment: Thanks!
It looks that basically on windows *you have to* use `gitdir/i:`, not `gitdir`...

Comment: Also trailing slash is required, for me it doesn't work without it.

Comment: For Christ sake, the trailing slash thing wasted me almost an hour. Thanks!

Comment: The docs have a very precise description of how leading/trailing slashes are handled: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_conditional_includes

Answer (score 26):

The accepted answer, while helpful, does not answer the question.

As of this writing, **includeIf only works inside a git initialized folder.**

So if you cd into "~/Documents/webstorm/corporate/somegitproject" and run the command the output will be as expected:

```
$ cd ~/Documents/webstorm/corporate/somegitproject
$ git config user.email
corporate@email.com
```

This is probably a defect against git, since a user would expect this to work similarly in "~/Documents/webstorm/corporate/" as well.

Comment: my first guess was that it is a bug. Do you think this should be logged?

Comment: Is not a bug, see Git mailing list for [context](https://public-inbox.org/git/F55DC360-9C1E-45B9-B8BA-39E1001BD620@gmail.com/).

Comment: This is not a defect nor a bug. It works as intended. The `gitdir` condition works against `.git` dir. No `.git` dir - no `include`. But the question is: why does it matter for you that `git config` doesn't show your `user.email` when you have no `.git` dir there? I can't think of a reason for why this would matter since there's no `.git` there, so there's no way anything can use the config info at that location. The only reason I can think of is that it can be confusing in some cases.

Comment: this is a problem because if you want to clone a repo, you cannot set your git environment *before* cloning it, only afterward. So it's a catch22 situation if you need a specific git config to clone a repo.

Comment: @dcsan It turns out that the IncludeIf does function outside of an inited git repo, and cloning based on dynamic credentials does work.

Comment: as @studog said, I can also confirm that `git clone` took the config based on "includeIf" (in my case my work project require `http.sslbackend=schannel` setting to be able to work with the remote)

Comment: @MariuszPawelski I'd forgotten I made that comment. Since then I've learned that what `git clone` actually does is create the empty directory, cd into it, `git init`, _and at this point the IncludeIf will work_, and now the clone occurs, and after it's completed, cd back into the original directory. From the user point of view, it looks like IncludeIf works outside of a git directory, but in really does not.

Comment: @studog I'd say "cd into it" and "cd back" are strong assumptions. More likely git stays put in the parent directory, but runs `init` and the subsequent operations with a "git dir" handle on the child directory, something like the `--git-dir` option. It's probably also cleaner to describe it that way, because `includeIf gitdir` doesn't care about the `$CWD`; it cares about what the git dir at hand is (which can change with `--git-dir`).

Answer (score 10):

There is a typo here:

```
[includeIf "gitdir: ~/Documents/webstorm/corporate/"]
path = .gitconfig-work
```

There should be no space after `gitdir:`:

```
[includeIf "gitdir:~/Documents/webstorm/corporate/"]
path = .gitconfig-work
```

Removing it will correct the behavior within an initialized Git repository.

This will show the entire Git configuration and what Git config files it is drawn from:

```
git config --list --show-origin
```

CAVEAT: If you run this inside a Git repository it will show values from **.gitconfig-work**, but it will not if you are within **~/Documents/webstorm/corporate/**, but outside a Git repository.

Answer (score 0):

The OP concludes that includeIf functionality does not work in normal non-git directories.

This is provably incorrect for at least the configuration item core.sshCommand. If a conditionally included .gitconfig has a core.sshCommand configured, it is used in git clone operations in normal non-git directories.

It seems that the part that doesn't work properly is the display of conditionally included configuration. Which is quite problematic and interferes with tracking down broken configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I mapped a directory to a drive on a windows machine with `subst D: <mapped directory>`. If you want to know the path of your repository you can use this command in the repository context:

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

The output was something like this:

```
<mapped directory>/<name of repository>
```

So I changed it to:

```
[includeIf "gitdir:<mapped directory>/"]
    path = .gitconfig-work
```

Now it works for me.