# Is there way to run git hook before/after 'git add' command?

Tags: git, automation, githooks

I checked `git help hooks` and either it is impossible or I missed this.

I want this rather than `pre-commit` as program in repository generates files, as result my current workflow is

`git add -A
ruby script_stored_in_repository_that_generates_something.rb
<checking generated work that is not tracked in the repository>
git commit -m "what was changed"`

and I want to eliminate manual script run as pointless.

I know I can use `pre-commit` hook, but I prefer to edit work while code is staged rather than reverting/undoing/amending commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think that exists. I think the closest you can come is to make an alias. You can't override git commands with alias so you must use a different name than 'add'.

```
git config alias.ad '!./my_script.sh && git add'
```

Comment: "You can't override git commands with alias so you must use a different name than 'add'." It is aliased already, so that it is not a problem. Now I need to figure out how to make this alias so for repositories without this file the script will not be run.

Comment: You could perhaps look into conditional includes and only have the alias defined for a specific folder https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801729/is-it-possible-to-have-different-git-config-for-different-projects/43884702#43884702 @MateuszKonieczny