# How can I set the git username and email for every repo in a directory?

Tags: git, github

I have a personal computer that I also use for work. For work, I have to upload files to a large amount of github repos and in order to do so using my work github account, I need to pass `git config user.name [USERNAME]` and `git config user.email [EMAIL]` in every repo. I have all these repos located within a single parent directory (which is not a repo). Is there any way for me to set the git username and git email for every github repo within this parent directory?

Comment: I guess your best bet would be creating a bash script that iterates over subdirectories and sets name and email for each repo.

Comment: Why not to set it globally?

Comment: See also [Is it possible to have different Git configuration for different projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801729/is-it-possible-to-have-different-git-configuration-for-different-projects).

Answer (score 2):

You could make your parent directory the "superproject" and all repositories submodules of this superproject. Please see [Git Submodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)

After configuring this you can loop through your submodules as followed:

```
git submodule foreach git config user.name  "User Name"
git submodule foreach git config user.email "user@abc.com"
```

Answer (score 2):

**If you want the same name for every project then set it globally:**

```
$ git config --global --add user.name "Your name"
$ git config --global --add user.email "your_em@il.com"
```

If you want to set different name and email for different projects do the following.

Find all `.git/config` files and store them in the file:

```
$ for gitdirr in `find . -type d -name ".git"` ; do echo $gitdirr/config ; done > gitconfigs
```

Find all git configs containing `[user]` section, probably they will have `name` and `email` set, so you have to change them to the ones you want:

```
$ grep -li "\[user\]" `cat gitconfigs`
```

Open the files and check if names are the ones you want, change if not.

Find files which do not contain user section:

```
$ grep -Li "\[user\]" `cat gitconfigs`
```

Open each file and add user section with `name` and `email` keys with values specific for the project:

```
[user]
    name = Your name for the project
    email = Your em@il for the project
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick python script that should be easily extendible.

Usage:

```bash
# name and email
./gitconfig.py --name="First Last" --email="your@email.com" --parent-folder="/path/to/folder"

# just email
./gitconfig.py --email="your@email.com" --parent-folder="/path/to/folder"
```

Python script `gitconfig.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import argparse
import subprocess

def set_git_config(repo_path, name, email):
    if name:
        subprocess.check_call(['git', 'config', 'user.name', name], cwd=repo_path)
        print(f"Git username set to {name} for repository at {repo_path}")
    if email:
        subprocess.check_call(['git', 'config', 'user.email', email], cwd=repo_path)
        print(f"Git email set to {email} for repository at {repo_path}")

def walk_and_set_git_config(parent_folder, name, email):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(parent_folder):
        if '.git' in dirs:
            repo_path = os.path.join(root, '.git')
            set_git_config(repo_path, name, email)

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Set git username and email for all repositories under a parent folder")
    parser.add_argument("--parent-folder", default=os.getcwd(), help="Path to the parent folder containing git repositories")
    parser.add_argument("--name", help="Name to set for git repositories")
    parser.add_argument("--email", help="Email to set for git repositories")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    walk_and_set_git_config(args.parent_folder, args.name, args.email)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```