# How to git clone without manual config?

Tags: git

Whenever I `git clone ...url...` I have to spend too much time doing all the `git config ...`s.

Is there a way through which I can move around all the *project specific* (I'm aware of the `--global` flag but that's not what I want to achieve) config on different computers? If yes, what is it.

Comment: You may create a git repository for your .gitconfig ? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801729/is-it-possible-to-have-different-git-config-for-different-projects to see how to define conditional global configuration.

Comment: What config do you need to clone the repository?

Answer (score 0):

You can store it inside a project in a file (for example .gitconfig).
And than after `git clone` you would have to simply `git config --local include.path <path to gitconfig relative to .git directory>`. When you store your config in main dir in repository as .gitconfig then your command should be:

```
 git config --local include.path ../.gitconfig
```