# git: Different configuration for different repositories

Tags: git, configuration

My git repositories are in `~/Projects` folder. Every repository name starts with indicator, if it is personal or work repository:

```
~/Projects
  |-- personal-repo1
  |-- personal-repo2
  |-- work-repo1
  |-- work-repo2
  |-- work-repo3
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43884702/7122272), I have set my `~/.gitconfig` file to use different email for my personal reposiories and for my work repositories like this:

```
[user]
        email = my.personal@email.com
        name = Jaroslav Bezdek

[includeIf "gitdir:~/Projects/work-*"]
        path = ~/.gitconfig_work
```

My `~/.gitconfig_work` looks like this:

```
[user]
        email = my.work@email.com
```

However, git is still using my personal email address for both personal and work repositories. Please, could you help me with that? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a final `/`:

```
[includeIf "gitdir:~/Projects/work-*/"]
```