# 'includeif' is not working on git-for-windows

Tags: git, git-for-windows

I've recently upgraded to `git version 2.33.1.windows.1`
and `includeif` does not seem to be working.
Can anyone else confirm? I can't remember what my previous git version was.

My config is as follows:

.gitconfig

```
[user]
  name = crowne
  email = crowne@fakemail.com
[includeIf "gitdir:E:/work/**"]
  path = ~/.gitconfig_work
```

.gitconfig_work

```
[user]
    name = name.surname
    email = name.surname@work.com
```

The reason I upgraded was that the `includeif` was not taking effect recursively
on directories nested more than one directory below `E:/work/`

Since the upgrade it doesn't seem to be taking effect at all.

`>git config -l --show-origin`

Only shows entries from:

- C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig
- C:/Users/crowne/.gitconfig

I don't see any entries from:

- C:/Users/crowne/.gitconfig_work

Comment: Try `[includeIf "gitdir/i:E:/work"]` (case-insensitive, no `**`).

Comment: I tried, but its still not working

Comment: This is no longer a problem for me, I'm currently on git version 2.34.1.windows.1  
  
however I'm also on a new computer and my work include path is now  
  
[includeIf "gitdir/i:**/work/**"]
 path = ~/.gitconfig_work

Answer (score 7):

I have tried git v2.35.1 and the magic was for me, to drop the `**` in the end and keep the trailing slash `/` alone. I added also the `/i` option to ignore be case-insensitive.

.gitconfig, which worked for me

```
[user]
  name = crowne
  email = crowne@fakemail.com
[includeIf "gitdir/i:E:/work/"]
  path = ~/.gitconfig_work
```

not working a)

```
[user]
  name = crowne
  email = crowne@fakemail.com
[includeIf "gitdir/i:E:/work/**"]
  path = ~/.gitconfig_work
```

not working b)

```
[user]
  name = crowne
  email = crowne@fakemail.com
[includeIf "gitdir/i:E:/work"]
  path = ~/.gitconfig_work
```

Comment: similar issue under ubuntu, after switched from Bionic (git v2.17) to Focal (git v2.25.1), I had `[includeIf "gitdir:~/workspace/*"]` and it worked under old version. Now I remove * : `[includeIf "gitdir:~/workspace/"]` equivalent to _/home/myusername/workspace/**_ and it works fine, https://stackoverflow.com/a/54125961/6614155

Comment: The flat `/i` is important, because of the drive letter `C:` or `c:`... who knows what git thinks is the truth...

Comment: if you test with `git config --get user.email` make sure you are actually in a git repo inside the folder, otherwise it will return the default value

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working for me on windows by using the following:

.gitconfig

```
[includeIf "gitdir:**"]
path = C:/Users/myusername/.gitconfig-personal
[includeIf "gitdir:C:/Users/myusername/Desktop/work/**"]
path = C:/Users/myusername/.gitconfig-work
```

.gitconfig-personal and .gitconfig-work

```
[user]
name = My Name
email = myEmail@provider.com
```

So in this case it will always default to my normal email in .gitconfig-personal and in case I go to any of the repositories in the work folder it will use the .gitconfig-work details.
(I haven't tried using the case incentivise option)

Comment: isn't `[includeIf "gitdir:**"]` effectively `[include]`?