# Manage github and gitlab account in one device

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have logged in my Github (using Github Desktop) and Gitlab account in my laptop and it has different name and email. When I commit my code to my Gitlab repo, the account that make a commit is Github account. And when I check using `git config --list` it shows my Github account.

How to seperate my Github and Gitlab account so it will use correct account when do some commit etc. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In your GitLab repository folder, set the proper name/email

```
git config user.name "your Name"
git config user.email your@email.com
```

That way, you will create commits using the *local* setting to that specific repository.

---

Another approach is to put your GitLab repositories in a `gitlab` folder.
That way, you can include in your global config `~/.gitconfig` a config dedicated to GitLab **[depending on the path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43884702/6309)**:

```
[includeIf "gitdir:~/gitlab/"]
  path = .gitconfig-gitlab
```

That means you don't have to set your user/email for each individual GitLab repositories you are cloning.