# Change where VS Code looks for SSH key when git pulling and pushing

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, ssh

I work on a virtual machine. The C drive on the machine gets wiped every time I log on and off. However, I have a personal drive in my network that persists. When I git pull and push from the terminal in VS Code at every new sign in, I have to copy my .ssh folder into my C drive from my persistent drive. Is there a way to change my VS Code configuration to look for my ssh folder in my persistent network drive? Alternatively, is there a way to keep my .ssh folder in my C drive between wipes?

Answer (score 1):

my personal choice to set custom key location is to do first time clone with

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.orgA"
```

and then edit [git core section in project configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16682441/10441915)
to have

```
[core]
...
sshCommand = ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.orgA
```

this could be applicable also for network drives

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe not- at least not at the time of this writing.

For one thing, I searched for SSH-related vanilla VS Code settings and didn't find any with "SSH" in their name.

I also looked to see if OpenSSH allows to configure the directory used for user config, and it seems like the answer is no. The description of the `~/.ssh/` file path doesn't say anything about configuring the location, and [this Arch Linux wiki page which is generally a good reference for configuring application directories](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XDG_Base_Directory) says that discussion was raised about making OpenSSH support the XDG spec was closed as "wont-fix" and also says that many SSH clients just presume on the existence of that specific directory at that path ([source](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2050)).

If in some future for some reason OpenSSH and other SSH clients decide to add a mechanism to change this, it might be possible to achieve what you want by modifying [`core.sshCommand`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coresshCommand) to pass some argument, or to set some environment variable to change what directory is used. If the approach involves changing `core.sshCommand`, it might be necessary to manually set [`ssh.variant`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-sshvariant) as well.

As for your virtual machine's C: drive being wiped, I suggest you write a script to copy your host machine's SSH config to the virtual machine.